# Delay function call without pausing application in Java

Tags: java, delay, settimeout, sleep, wait

I want my application to show something in a label for a couple seconds and then change. But I don't want my application to be sleeping during this time. It must be functional.

`wait()` and `sleep()` will make my application not work during this time. Is there anything like javascript's `setTimeout()` in Java, that will continue executing the code and execute a line after a period of time?

Comment: What GUI are you using?

Comment: Why don't you spawn a new thread and when it runs, its waits for a given length of time before executing?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to include more sophisticated libraries you might use [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (as mentioned by @VGR), [`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) or [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Example using `javax.swing.Timer`:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");

Timer timer = new Timer(15000, e -> label.setText("Bye"));

timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Example using `ScheduledExecutorService` (remember that the actual logic touching UI components probably must be run from the GUI thread ([AWT event dispatch thread in case of Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-)), not executor's thread):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");

Runnable task = () -> SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> label.setText("Bye"));

executor.schedule(task, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The executor runs background threads so you should shutdown it when you no longer need it.

Comment: No mention of [java.Swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)?

Comment: Great suggestion @VGR. I have added it to the answer.